# Powershell Rename-Item: Illegal characters in path

Tags: powershell

I want to rename all files of a folder and wrote this script:

```powershell
$array = @' 
Trautes Heim
Das Fett muss weg
Revierkämpfe
Männergespräche
Ernste Absichten
Die Klette
Der Verlobungsring
Späte Schule für Doug
Verkehrsprobleme
Truthahn à la Mama
Klein aber fein
Liebe ist …
Alte Geschichten
Auf den Hund gekommen
Alt, dick und hässlich
Valentinstag
Die Verkaufte Frau
Der Ruf der Straße
Freundschaftsdienste
Die Neue Kollegin
Bärenhunger
Ich will Dich, ich will Dich nicht
Endlich allein
Auf Wiedersehen, Arthur
Auf Eis gelegt
'@.Split("`n");
$inProcessPath = ".\"

$i = 0
Get-ChildItem -Include @("*.mp4") -Path $inProcessPath -Recurse | 
Foreach-Object {
    $source = ""+$_.FullName
    $newFileName="" + "S01E0$($i+1) $($array[$i]).mp4";
    $i++

    Write-Host $source    
    Rename-Item -Path $source -NewName $newFileName
}
```

All filenames get printed properly but the rename function throws an odd error and I can't seem to fix it:

```
PS V:\Neu> .\names.ps1
V:\Neu\King Of Queens Season 1 1-1.mp4
Rename-Item : Illegales Zeichen im Pfad.
In V:\Neu\names.ps1:41 Zeichen:5
+     Rename-Item -Path $source -NewName $newFileName
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Rename-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

And so on... I don't what's wrong there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code splits on newline, but depending on your script encoding, your newlines are actually `\r\n` so you're leaving an invisible `\r` in all the names.  Use `.Split()` without arguments.

Comment: It might also help you debug if you `Write-Host ("Alt={0}     Neu={1}" -f $source,$newFileName)`, so that you can see the names you're getting, and possibly spot the illegal character.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That was it! Thank you so much!